# SAS HBA server won't boot under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, sas, hba

I Have a Supermicro server with a SAS HBA card, connected to a 44-disk array. It worked perfectly fine, until I reinstalled it on Ubuntu 22.04. Now it won't boot.

It hangs right after bios/uefi initialization, right when the kernel takes control. At that point, the drives light up one by one in some (to me illogical, yet consistent) order, which it keeps doing. There is no output on the screen, just blank.

The funny thing is...

- It does boot fine when SAS cable to the disk array is NOT connected. Once it is booted without disks, I can connect the disk enclosure with the sas cable, the disks are recognized, and I can import the ZFS pool. However, when the cable is connected during boot, it hangs.
- It also boots fine (with all disks connected) in an Ubuntu installer from USB/PXE. I can even find all disks in the installation menus.

I tried reinstalling from a USB boot where all drives were correctly recognized, both in regular server as well as minimal mode. Once installed, same issue, both installations halt right after the uefi initialization. I also reran the installer without network (avoiding updates) to make sure this isn't related to an updated driver, but to no avail.

Most things I can think of (rootdelay, root-on-zfs, multipath misconfig) would yield some feedback from kernel/initramfs. Any hints to what the cause may be are appreciated!

**Specs** (Just in case they matter):

```
- SuperMicro H11SSW-NT with 64GB ram
- drives:
  - NVME M.2 100G boot INTEL SSDPEL1K100GA
  - NVME U.2 2TB pool INTEL SSDPE2KX020T8
  - NVME U.2 1TB pool INTEL SSDPE2KX010T8
  - 44x SAS Seagate ST16000NM002G
- PCIe
    - SAS controller: LSI SAS3216 PCIe Fusion-MPT SAS-3 (rev 01)
```